# How does Thespian's Stage work with Spreading Seas?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have a [Thespian's Stage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thespian%27s%20Stage) and a [Dark Depths](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Depths) that is currently an Island (because of [Spreading Seas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spreading%20Seas)). What happens if I use Thespian's Stage to copy the Dark Depths?

Do I get a copy of Dark Depths, or do I get an Island? If I get Dark Depths, I assume it has 0 snow counters so I can immediately make Marit Lage. If I get an Island, does the legend rule apply? If not, does anything happen if I later destroy the Spreading Seas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Thespian's Stage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thespian%27s%20Stage) will copy the details printed on the land card being copied, these are termed the land's copiable values.

In the case of a [Dark Depths](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Depths) enchanted by a [Spreading Seas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spreading%20Seas) the Thespian's Stage will become an un-enchanted copy of Dark Depths, with no ice counters on it.
As Spreading Seas does not change the enchanted land's name or whether it's legendary, the legend rule will kick in, and you must choose to keep either the enchanted copy of Dark Depths, or the Thespian's Stage.

---

**Applicable rulings from cards:**
*[Thespian's Stage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thespian%27s%20Stage)*

> A land's copiable values are those printed on it, as modified by other copy effects. Counters and other effects aren't copied. Notably, if you copy a land that is also a creature because of a temporary effect (such as Celestial Colonnade), Thespian's Stage will become just the “unanimated” land.

*[Spreading Seas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spreading%20Seas)*

> The enchanted land loses its existing land types and any abilities printed on it. It now has the land type Island and has the ability to tap to add {u} to its controller's mana pool. Spreading Seas doesn't change the enchanted land's name or whether it's legendary, basic, or snow.